# multiplayer game data model design

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

Here is my dynamodb table design for game in pending state that has two players. Game state can change form pending -> live -> over

```
PK      SK      State    Name
gid1    state   pending 
gid1    pid1             alex
gid1    pid2             john
```

Now I want to query what pending games specific user is part of. In order to do so I have to duplicate Game State to each game player item and create GSI like this.

```
GSIPK   GSISK   PK
alex    pending gid1
john    pending gid1
```

This duplication works fine until I want to update game state. It means I must update all game's users State as well and if game has a lot of players that might be slow and expensive.

Is there a better design to model that parent/child relation where child depends on parent's attribute value?

Comment: logically it is not possible because there can be only one-one relationship b/w player name and state. because we would want to use only 1 call to fetch the result. Now to update all n user state you would need to do n updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems no obvious reason to duplicate the game state. You could continue with your current model. Lookup the games a player is involved in using the GSI, then take the set of results and iterate them. For each game a player is involved in, get the GameState item from the base table. Add each game to a set where the set key is state.

Its one extra step, so a little more code, but it would cost very little in terms of database throughput.

The other option, which seems more obvious to me, is to have two separate tables; one for game players and one for game state.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of. I will use BatchGetItem to read current game state from original game item for each game id that user query returns. This will eliminate unnecessary state updates and should scale well if I add more game attributes that get changed over time.